# How prove a sequence has infinitely many square numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Question**

Suppose $u$ and $v$ are positive integers and $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence with $a_{1}=u+v$ and

> $$\begin{cases}
> a_{2m}=a_{m}+u\\
> a_{2m+1}=a_{m}+v,
> \end{cases}$$ 
>   for every $m \ge 1$.

Let $s_{m}=a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{m}$, show that $\{s_{m}\}$  has infinitely many square 
numbers.

My  try: since

> $$a_{1}=u+v, a_{2}=2u+v,a_{3}=u+2v,a_{4}=3u+v,a_{5}=2u+2v,a_{6}=2u+2v,$$
>   $$a_{7}=u+3v,a_{8}=4u+v,a_{9}=3u+2v,a_{10}=3u+2v,a_{11}=2u+3v,\cdots\cdots\cdots$$
>   then
>   $$s_{1}=u+v,s_{2}=3u+2v,s_{3}=4(u+v),s_{4}=7u+5v,s_{5}=9u+7v,s_{6}=11u+9v $$
>   $$s_{7}=12(u+v),s_{8}=16u+13v,s_{9}=19u+15v,s_{10}=22u+17v,s_{11}=24u+20v,\cdots$$
>   and we have

Comment: Are `u,v` known to be different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’ll demonstrate one way to approach the problem, leaving some of the intermediate proofs and the final step of the argument to you.

We have $a_1=u+v$ and

$$\begin{align*}
a_{2m}&=a_{m}+u\\
a_{2m+1}&=a_{m}+v\;.
\end{align*}$$

Gathering a little data, we find that

$$\begin{array}{l|l}
a_1=u+v&s_1=u+v=a_1\\ \hline
a_2=2u+v\\
a_3=u+2v&s_3=4u+4v=4a_1\\ \hline
a_4=3u+v\\
a_5=2u+2v\\
a_6=2u+2v\\
a_7=u+3v&s_7=12u+12v=12a_1\\ \hline
a_8=4u+v\\
a_9=3u+2v\\
a_{10}=3u+2v\\
a_{11}=2u+3v\\
a_{12}=3u+2v\\
a_{13}=2u+3v\\
a_{14}=2u+3v\\
a_{15}=u+4v&s_{15}=32u+32v=32a_1\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

We notice that at least as far as our data go, if $2^{n-1}\le k<2^n$, then the coefficients of $u$ and $v$ in $a_k$ sum to $n+1$. It appears, moreover, that if $k=2^{n-1}+\ell$, then the coefficients of $u$ and $v$ in $a_k$ and $a_{2^n-1-\ell}$ are interchanged, so that $a_k+a_{2^n-1-\ell}=(n+1)(u+v)=(n+1)a_1$, and therefore

$$\sum_{k=2^{n-1}}^{2^n-1}a_k=2^{n-2}(n+1)a_1\tag{1}$$

for $n\ge 2$, and

$$s_{2^n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1}a_k=\left(1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}2^k(k+3)\right)a_1\;.\tag{2}$$

It’s not too hard to prove $(1)$ by induction on $n$, and that proves $(2)$. It’s possible to solve $(2)$ in closed form starting from scratch, but there’s a shortcut: for $n=1,2,3,4$ the coefficients of $a_1$ in $s_{2^n-1}$ are $1,4,12,32$; if we feed that to [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/), the first return is [A$001787$](http://oeis.org/A001787), and a quick computation shows that this sequence matches the coefficients of $a_1$ in $s_{31}$ and $s_{63}$ as well. If it really is our sequence, then

$$s_{2^n-1}=n2^{n-1}a_1\tag{3}$$

for $n\ge 1$. Given $(2)$, it’s easy to prove $(3)$ by induction on $n$.

Now it suffices to prove that if $a_1$ is any positive integer, there are infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that $n2^{n-1}a_1$ is a perfect square, and this is pretty straightforward.

Comment: nice sir :) nicely explained